# Enviar múltiples archivos de diferentes inputs file a PHP con AJAX (JS Puro)

Tags: php, ajax, fileupload, blob, formdata

Tengo el problema de querer hacer que PHP reciba todos los archivos que fueron seleccionados en los diferentes inputs file que se generan dinámicamente con JavaScript. Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de conseguir enviar múltiples archivos de diferentes inputs a PHP mediante AJAX para luego tratar cada archivo en PHP de alguna manera.

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

**HTML**

```
<div class="contenedor__examen">

            <div class="contenedor__examen__seccion">
                <p>Nombre de la Pregunta</p>
                <input type="text" class="inputTexto nombrePregunta">

                <p>Respuesta Correcta</p>
                <input type="text" class="inputTexto respuestaCorrecta">

                <div class="contenedor__audio">

                    <input type="file" id="real-file" hidden="hidden" name="audio" class="botonAudio">
                    <button type="button" id="custom-button" class="botonInput" numinput="1">Subir Audio</button>
                    <br>
                    <span id="custom-text" class="textoInput">Ningún audio seleccionado</span>

                </div>

                <p>Texto al Reproducir</p>
                <input type="text" class="inputTexto inputFinal textoAlReproducir">
            </div>

        </div>
```

El bloque de código de arriba se genera múltiples veces con la algunas diferencias agregadas mediante JS.

**JS**

```
valoresAudios = [];

obtenerAudios = () => {
    valoresAudios = [];
    let audios = document.querySelectorAll(".botonAudio");
    audios.forEach((_elemento, indice) => {
        valor = audios[indice];

        valoresAudios.push(valor);
    });
};

btnEnviarExamen.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let nombreDelExamen = nombreExamen.value;
    let temarioAlQuePertenece = valueSelect;

    let enviarExamen = new FormData();
    enviarExamen.append("nombreExamen", nombreDelExamen);
    enviarExamen.append("temarioAlQuePertenece", temarioAlQuePertenece);

    enviarExamen.append(
        "valorNombrePreguntas",
        JSON.stringify(valoresNombresPreguntas)
    );

    enviarExamen.append(
        "valoresRespuestasCorrectas",
        JSON.stringify(valoresRespuestasCorrectas)
    );

    enviarExamen.append("valoresAudios", valoresAudios);

    enviarExamen.append(
        "revaloresTextoAlReproducirspuestas",
        JSON.stringify(valoresTextoAlReproducir)
    );

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/src/admin/examenes/subirExamen.php", true);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(enviarExamen);
});
```

Hay más código JS pero que no creo que sea relevante, mi problema es enviar por AJAX a PHP todos los inputs file para poder subirlos al servidor y almacenar su ubicación en MYSQL.

**PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/src/admin/comprobarAdmin.php");
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/src/conexionbd.php");

$valoresAudio = $_POST["valoresAudios"];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($valoresAudio); $i++)
{
    var_dump($_FILES["audio"]['name']);
}
```

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia es bienvenida. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En tu código yo veo un solo input file, no varios como dices en la pregunta. ¿Dónde están los otros? Sea como sea, para que se envíen tienes que ponerlos en el objeto `FormData` usando [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Comment: Por que no usa un formulario? es mucho más sencillo. Además junto con ``fetch``  y aplicando el evento ``submit()`` para enviar un ``FormData()``, recibe en php todos los datos de un formulario usando el atributo ``name=" "``  en los inputs.... mucho más practico y limpio

Comment: @A.Cedano solo ves uno en la explicación que puse, no se si habrás leído que se agregan varios bloques de HTML dinámicamente. Usé FormData y append, revisa de nuevo el código, el problema es que no se enviar múltiples archivos por AJAX.

Comment: @mafu un formulario no vale porque solo recibe el último input file si todos tienen el mismo name, además tengo que enviar los array generados en javascript y a la vez los input files. Si pudieras explicar el método fetch te lo agradecería.

Comment: He leído que se agregan varios bloques dinámicos y que intentas enviar varios archivos desde diferentes inputs, por eso precisamente mi comentario anterior, **se necesita un ejemplo mínimo y verificable** en las preguntas para tener una idea completa del problema y poder ayudar de la mejor manera. En este caso, dado que no usas un formulario, tendrás que meter los archivos de alguna manera en el FormData, por ejemplo, asignándole una clase a los 'input` file, recorriéndolos y metiendo cada archivo en el FormData para luego enviarlo completo vía Ajax.

Comment: Con respecto al ejemplo mínimo y verificable bastaría con clonar el HTML que puse varias veces, aún así si deseas que muestre todo el código me dices para actualizar la pregunta, no quería cargar de mucho código la pregunta. Gracias por la ayuda @A.Cedano, ¿podrías explicar cómo hacer eso de meter los archivos en el form data? me quedé botado xD El problema es que no se mandar múltiples archivos mediante form data, ya tienen una clase con la cual se pueden recorrer con queryselectorall

Comment: @C0D3BREAK3R Bro, con el ejemplo en mi comentario, es posible tomar todos los valores con un mismo ``attr name=" "`` retornando un array (``new FormData(var_formulario).getAll("elname");``), luego en php solo sería extraer. Sobre explicar el método fetch, tendría que hacer un nuevo post quizás, o editar la pregunta con su intento de código y podría responder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias a @A.Cedano por toda la ayuda brindad ya que él me orientó mucho para dar con la solución.

Para enviar múltiples archivos por AJAX a PHP hay que acceder a cada uno de ellos, por ejemplo:

```
let audios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file].botonAudio");
```

Luego, para enviarlos hay que añadirlos al `FormData()`, aquí un ejemplo:

```
audios.forEach((audio) => {
        enviarExamen.append("audio[]", audio.files[0]);
    });
```

La clave para poder recibir múltiples archivos en PHP es nombrar la clave (valga la redundancia) que vamos a enviar con dos corchetes, por ejemplo: `audio[]`, además el valor de la clave debe ser el nombre del arreglo que estamos recorriendo pero añadiendo `.files[0]`, ejemplo: `audio.files[0]`. Por eso cuando intenté con `audio.files[indice]` no funcionaba porque el índice tiene que ser 0.

Para recorrer los datos de los archivos enviados a PHP recomiendo enviar por POST la cantidad de archivos, ejemplo:

```
enviarExamen.append("cantAudios", audios.length);
```

En PHP para tratar a los archivos realizamos un ciclo `for` a `$_FILES` y accedemos a cada valor del array con sus respectivos nombres de índices: `name`, `tmp_name`, etc y especificando el índice del valor al que queremos acceder, aquí un ejemplo:

```
$archivos = $_FILES;
$cantAudios = $_POST['cantAudios'];

$rutasAudios = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $cantAudios; $i++)
{
    $nombreAudio = $archivos['audio']['name'][$i];
    $temporalAudio = $archivos['audio']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $rutaAudio = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/audios/$nombreAudio";
    array_push($rutasAudios, $rutaAudio);

    move_uploaded_file($temporalAudio, $rutaAudio);
}
```

Para nada es complicado enviar múltiples archivos por AJAX, lo recomiendo completamente en vez de usando los formularios ya que además podemos mandar otros datos en arreglos a PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Tú puedes alcanzar los input file por la clase `botonAudio` con `querySelectorAll()` y luego recorrer cada input para incluir los archivos en el objeto FormData.

Sería más o menos así. Para la prueba de concepto he ligado la acción al click del botón. Algo curioso en tu código es que los input están ocultos, entonces, no se entiende cómo se podrá seleccionar archivos desde ellos ¿? (he quitado la propiedad hidden para poder hacer la prueba).

Otra cosa es que cuides de que no se creen inputs con el mismo id.

```js
var btnSend = document.getElementById('custom-button');
btnSend.onclick = function() {

  var allFiles = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file].botonAudio');
  let formData = new FormData();
  allFiles.forEach(f => {
    /*Verificamos que hay archivos*/
    if (f.files.length > 0) {
      formData.append("audio[]", f.files[0]);
    }
  });

  /*Test del formData*/

  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="contenedor__audio">

  <input type="file" id="real-file1" name="audio" class="botonAudio">

  <input type="file" id="real-file2" name="audio" class="botonAudio">


  <button type="button" id="custom-button" class="botonInput" numinput="1">Subir Audio</button>
  <br>
  <span id="custom-text" class="textoInput">Ningún audio seleccionado</span>

</div>
```

Quizá esto podría ser más simple si usaras un formulario. Cuando solicitas FormData desde un formulario éste mete dentro todos los elementos con etiqueta `name`. El único problema es que para los input de tipo file no verifica si están vacíos o no. Si esta validación es importante para ti podrás hacerla de varios modos (no me meto con eso porque se aleja del propósito de la pregunta).

Con un formulario el código quedaría así más o menos, este es el [ejemplo básico de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), en el que se explica también cómo agregar datos adicionales al FormData.

```js
/*Referencia al form por su nombre*/
var form = document.forms.namedItem("mForm");

/*Listener del submit*/
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
  /*Objeto FormData*/
  var oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("mForm"));

  /*En caso se necesitarlo*/
  oData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
  
  /*Para que no se recargue la página*/
  ev.preventDefault();

  /*Test de datos*/
  for (var pair of oData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }
  
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="contenedor__audio">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="mForm">

  <input type="file" id="real-file1" name="audio" class="botonAudio">

  <input type="file" id="real-file2" name="audio" class="botonAudio">


  <button type="submit" id="custom-button" class="botonInput" numinput="1">Subir Audio</button>
  <br>
  <span id="custom-text" class="textoInput">Ningún audio seleccionado</span>
  <input type="submit" value="Stash the file!" />
</form>
</div>
```

Cualquiera de los métodos que elijas, ya es cuestión de pasar el objeto `formData` a la petición Ajax y recuperar los datos en el servidor de la manera adecuada.

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, con respecto a validar si tienen contenido no te preocupes que eso ya está en el código. Los inputs están ocultos pero con JS cuando se hace clic en un elemento visible se activa el click en el input invisible. Tengo una duda, con respecto a los parámetros f.id y f.files qué significan y luego recibiría los datos normalmente en PHP con $_FILES cuando envíe varios audios?

Comment: @C0D3BREAK3R aquí: `formData.append(f.id, f.files[0]);` se asociará a cada entrada de formData un par clave/valor, donde la clave será el `id` que tenga cada `input` y el valor será el archivo en sí (`f` en ese contexto sería cada archivo alcanzando por el selector). Luego en el servidor, trabajando con `$_FILES` podrás encontrar cada archivo asociado a su clave. En lugar de `id` puedes usar `name` por ejemplo, pero si los input tienen el mismo name no sé si eso dé problemas a la hora de recibirlos en el servidor, es cuestión de probar.

Comment: Gracias. Con un archivo puedo recibir normalmente los datos pero cuando son varios me encuentro con este problema: string(1) "p"
string(1) "r"
 <script data-prepros-origin-host="localhost" src="http://localhost:300/__prepros-server__/prepros.js"> </script> Las etiquetas script ignoralas que las agrega prepros.

Accedo a ellos así: $audios = $_FILES["audio"]['name'];
$audiosTipo = $_FILES["audio"]['type'];
$audiosTemporal = $_FILES["audio"]['tmp_name'];

Y el ciclo para recorrerlos es este: for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
    var_dump($audios[$i]);
}

Comment: No entiendo... ¿dónde te encuentras con ese problema @C0D3BREAK3R? ¿Es un mensaje de error o resultado de una depuración? ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: Ese mensaje lo recibo por AJAX y lo veo por la consola

Comment: Depura a files directamente con `var_dump($_FILES);` para ver qué muestra. Por si acaso  depura también esto: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Esto es lo que obtengo con var_dump($_FILES);

array(1) {
  ["audio"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "probar1.mp3"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "audio/mpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpA3BB.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(86787)
  }
}

Solamente me llega uno y debería haber 2

Comment: var_dump($_POST) se excede de caracteres para un comentario

Comment: @C0D3BREAK3R puede que los input tengan el mismo id y se estén sobre-escribiendo al hacer el `append`, quedando solamente uno por ese motivo. En la respuesta puse un `/*Test del formData*/` que convendría mostrar en consola para ver si se está mandando todo correctamente.

Comment: Yo mandé los audios no por el id si no utilizando la clave audio, de esta forma: audios.forEach((audio, indice) => {
        enviarExamen.append("audio", audio.files[indice]);
    });

y accedo a ellos así: let audios = document.querySelectorAll(".botonAudio");

Comment: @C0D3BREAK3R así la clave `audio` se sobre-escribe (me parece), deberías poner algo que la diferencie, por ejemplo: `enviarExamen.append("audio"+indice, audio.files[indice]);`

Comment: O, puedes intentar algo así: `enviarExamen.append("audio[]", audio.files[indice]);` para tener los archivos en un array llamado `audio`

Comment: cambie el ciclo y quedó así: audios.forEach((audio, indice) => {
        enviarExamen.append(`audio-${indice}`, audio.files[indice]);
    });

Pero todavía en var_dump($_FILES); llega 1 solo audio el cual es el primero

Comment: Prueba como te dije en el último comentario: `enviarExamen.append("audio[]", audio.files[indice]);`. Pero debes verificar que en ese `forEach` están entrando los dos archivos, o testear el FormData. ¿Seguro que hay dos archivos?

Comment: despues de probar: audios.forEach((audio, indice) => {
        enviarExamen.append("audio[]", audio.files[indice]);
    });

Recibo esto: array(1) {
  ["audio"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "probar1.mp3"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "audio/mpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF08C.tmp"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(86787)
    }
  }
}

Comment: estoy seguro que hay 2 inputs file cada uno con un audio distinto

Comment: No puede ser. No estés seguro de nada si no lo has verificado. Pon un `console.log` dentro de `audios.forEach`  si hay dos archivos ese console.log debe imprimirse dos veces. Si no, revisa el selector y los atributos/ubicación de los input porque uno estará fuera del alcance.

Comment: tras usar console.log(audio.files[indice]); en el for, efectivamente, solo devuelve un audio, lo cual es extraño

File {name: "probar1.mp3", lastModified: 1615907861621, lastModifiedDate: Tue Mar 16 2021 11:17:41 GMT-0400 (hora de verano de Cuba), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 86787, …}

Comment: Pues eso. Revisa el input  del audio que no aparece. ¿Tiene la clase que usas en el selector  para alcanzarlo? ¿Cómo estás creando `audios`, supongo que usas `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Todos los input file tienen la clase: botonAudio. y el ciclo que los recorre accede a ellos así:     let audios = document.querySelectorAll(".botonAudio");

Estoy pensando que quizás se está ejecutando el ciclo cuando solo existe un elemento, antes de agregar más y de presionar el botón para enviar. Cosa que no debería ocurrir pues el ciclo solo debería existir al hacer clic en el botón enviar.

Comment: Eso ya no sé, verifícalo en tu contexto... el código es amplio y esa parte debería ejecutarse al presionar el botón Enviar o algo así, no de otro modo. Y, por otra parte, yo no pondría el selector sólo con la clase, porque si otros elementos tienen esa clase el código se ejecutará para ellos y podrías tener problemas posteriores. En la respuesta indiqué una forma de selector sólo para los input tipo file con esa clase.

Comment: probé con tu forma de seleccionar, quedando así:

    let audios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file].botonAudio");

Pero me devuelve en el segundo undefined, también con mi forma de seleccionar

Comment: Esa debería ser la forma correcta (no digo que con eso se resuelva el problema). Si no está recogiendo todos debes revisar qué pasa en el contexto y verificar que no te has equivocado con el `input`, debe ser de tipo `file` y tener la clase `botonAudio` Si es así y el código se ejecuta al presionar Enviar no debería haber ningún problema,

Comment: cuando hago     console.log(audios);

de la variable:     let audios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file].botonAudio");

me devuelve esto:


NodeList(2) [input#real-file.botonAudio, input#real-file.botonAudio]
0: input#real-file.botonAudio
1: input#real-file.botonAudio
length: 2
__proto__: NodeList

Si se está detectando todos pero parece que el problema es a la hora de agregarlos en el formData.

Comment: Eso ya depende de tu contexto, entonces revísalo. Si pruebas el primer código de mi respuesta verás que si seleccionas dos archivos, éstos se agregan al formData sin problema, como muestra el test en consola.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120999/discussion-between-c0d3break3r-and-a-cedano).